# Ways to update many nested Documents with MongoTemplate without creating additional Update object

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I use [`MongoTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) to update a document using `findAndModify()` method.
There are nested documents inside one document. Example as following:

```
@Document
public class Company {
    private Long id;
    private String postalCode;
    private int floorCount;
    .....

    private Set<Car> cars;
}

class Car {
    private Long id;
    private int seatCount;
    private String color;
    .....
    private Engine engine;
}

class Engine {
    private Long id;
    private float engineVolume;
    .....   
}
```

In order to send to `findAndModify()` method as a parameter, I created an `Update` object for a `Company` as following:

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set("postalCode", company.getPostalCode());
update.set("floorCount", company.getFloorCount());
....
```

There are many `Car`s for a `Company` and update requests of `Company` comes with `Car` and `Engine` details.
To update `Car`s of `Company`, for nested `Car` documents, I write another separate `findAndModify()` method as following:

```
company.getCars().forEach(
                car -> {
                    mongoTemplate.findAndModify(
                            new Query(where("car._id").is(car.getId())),
                            new Update()
                                    .set("car.$[].seatCount", car.getSeatCount())
                                    .set("car.$[].color", car.getColor()),                                   
                            Car.class
                    );
                }
        );
```

What I want to do is I would like to build only one `Update` object for entire `Company` document with `Car` and `Engine` and set new values to only one `Update` object without iterating over `Car`s and without using  another separate `findAndModify()` method for `Car`. How can I do?